# Detect first launch on multiple ViewControllers - Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to have a UIView popup when a first-time User opens up a ViewController off of a tab bar controller - I just want to have a  message popup to explain how it works, like a tutorial.

I have implemented this for the first ViewController to popup on launch, but I want to have it check for first launch on multiple ViewControllers on my tab bar.   I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong here.  The view has: UIImageView, UITextView, and a UIButton I will use to "hide" the view when tapped.

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    isAppAlreadyLaunchedOnce()
   }

 func isAppAlreadyLaunchedOnce()->Bool{
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    if let isAppAlreadyLaunchedOnce = defaults.stringForKey("isAppAlreadyLaunchedOnce"){
        print("App already launched")

        return true
    }else{
        backgrdView.hidden = false
        messageView.hidden = false
        textView.hidden = false
        okButton.hidden = false
        tobysLabel.hidden = false


        return false
    }
}


@IBAction func okButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {

    backgrdView.hidden = true
    messageView.hidden = true
    tobysLabel.hidden = true
    textView.hidden = true
    okButton.hidden = true
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of checking isAppAlreadyLaunchedOnce check the launch of ViewController instead. So is firstVC is launch add to userDefaults firstVC as true. If second is launched set the secondVC as true. so this will maintain the userDefaults for individual VC's. Set your UserDefaults when OK was tapped. Then do this in all VC while you are checking the firstLaunch for each VC. Please keep the key different for different VC.

```
func isAppAlreadyLaunchedOnce()->Bool{
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
if defaults.boolForKey("firstVC") {
    print("First VC launched")
    return true
}else{
    backgrdView.hidden = false
    messageView.hidden = false
    textView.hidden = false
    okButton.hidden = false
    tobysLabel.hidden = false
    return false
}
}


@IBAction func okButtonTapped(sender: UIButton) {
    backgrdView.hidden = true
    messageView.hidden = true
    tobysLabel.hidden = true
    textView.hidden = true
    okButton.hidden = true
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "firstVC")
}
```

Comment: I think I am following here, although I'm not as familiar with NSUserDefaults as I should be.  How can I check a non-root ViewController if it is first launch though?

Comment: You can add the code inside `viewDidLoad` method. It gets called only once when the view is first loaded.

Comment: this works perfectly @Arun - thank you for the knowledge and your quick resolution.

Answer (score 0):

I use this to detect launch in a specific class.

It uses the class type name description as a key to set a true value in userDefaults after the first launch is detected. It reduces the need to use strings to set the keys and the need to set UserDefaults manually to true.

```
final class LaunchChecker <Entity> {

var wasLaunchedBefore: Bool {
    return defaults.bool(forKey: self.entityName)
}

let entityName: String
let defaults: UserDefaults

init(for entity: Entity.Type, defaults: UserDefaults = UserDefaults.standard) {
    self.entityName = String(describing: entity)
    self.defaults = defaults
}

func isFirstLaunch() -> Bool {
    if !wasLaunchedBefore {
        defaults.set(true, forKey: entityName)
        return true
    }
    return false
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
if LaunchChecker(for: MyViewController.self).isFirstLaunch() {
   doSomething()
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. While this code may answer the OP's question, it is better to include context, or reasoning as to why/how this solves the issue. This will help future visitors learn from your post and apply it to their own issues, and keeps SO a high value location for finding solutions to programming issues. Please edit if you can add some additional info. Thanks for your contribution!